# Is it allowed for a solicitor to advise and represent you while claiming hourly compensation from legal aid but also % of your winnings?

Tags: england-and-wales, fees, attorney-fees, legal-fees, contingency-fee

If solicitor gives you services and claims hourly fees from legal aid because you are eligible but also then takes a 15% cut of your final settlement amount, is this allowed or in a sense cheating the legal aid agency?

Why should they be allowed to do a no win no fee but then still get unconditional compensation already from LAA?